# Building Gnuarm toolchain from source

Tags: gcc, arm, gnu-toolchain

I want to build a toolchain from gnuarm.org from sources. I don't want to use binary version because i'm running x64 linux. Can you point me to some kind of tutorial?

Comment: I guess I have to supply some --target=elf-arm or something similar. Trying commands form official website and fighting error messages at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install *libx11-dev* to compile Insight.

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

Besides that, your own answer works just fine.

Edit: Oh, and you might miss termcap as well, get it here: [GNU Termcap](http://ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/termcap/termcap-1.3.1.tar.gz)

Edit2: Configure seems to be tight-ass about ignoring return values "*'xxx', declared with attribute warn_unused_result*", so you might need to modify the options or about 12 instances to catch return values to get clean build.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the default commands/parameters used to build the binary packages. Download the sources, unpack and issue them:

1. cd [binutils-build]
2. [binutils-source]/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=[toolchain-prefix] --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --with-float=soft
3. make all install
4. export PATH="$PATH:[toolchain-prefix]/bin"
5. cd [gcc-build]
6. [gcc-source]/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=[toolchain-prefix] --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --with-float=soft --enable-languages="c,c++" --with-newlib --with-headers=[newlib-source]/newlib/libc/include
7. make all-gcc install-gcc
8. cd [newlib-build]
9. [newlib-source]/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=[toolchain-prefix] --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --with-float=soft

   10. make all install
   11. cd [gcc-build]
   12. make all install
   13. cd [gdb-build]
   14. [gdb-source]/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=[toolchain-prefix] --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --with-float=soft
   15. make all install

lines 11-12 seem to have no effect.
Using gcc < 4.x is not advised, and building binutils can give the following error:

../../binutils-2.19/gas/config/tc-arm.c: In function 's_arm_unwind_save_mmxwr':
../../binutils-2.19/gas/config/tc-arm.c:3459: error: format not a string literal
and no format arguments

the solution is easy, just add "%s" as the FIRST parameter to the lines with error as the patch here suggests:
http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-binutils@gnu.org/msg06475.html

I could not build insight but i guess it is possible to debug it with something else.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download the sources available under "Files"
2. Unpack them
3. Go to each unpacked directory and type:

   ./configure --help

   to get the available options, then run

   ./configure [options]

   make

   make check

   make install

Comment: configuration must be made with some custom options, like specifying final target.

Comment: Which is why you type "./configure --help" to find out those options.  There's no way I can magically divine which of all the options the OP will want, so he'll have to do some digging on his own.

Comment: Wow, people don't like this answer, although it looks a lot like the OP's final solution (blue). Did I come off as rude saying that ./configure has a --help option?