# Why is a GCC cross compile not building `crti.o`?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

In an attempt to build a gcc 4.x.x cross compiler for arm, I'm stuck at a missing `crti.o` file in the `$BUILD_DIR/gcc` subdirectory.

An `strace` on the top level `Makefile` shows that the compiled `xgcc` is calling the cross-linker `ld` with `"crti.o"` as an argument.  I'm assuming that if the cross linking `ld` is being called, the native `/usr/lib/crti.o` is not what is needed.

I can see that in the gcc source tree there is a number of potential sources for a crti object (including `$SRC_DIR/gcc/config/arm/crti.asm`).

***How can I configure the gcc build to insure this file is built (or omitted from the `ld` command)?***

Here is my configure line:

```
/x-tools/build/gcc-4.5.0$ ../../src/gcc-4.5.0/configure --target=arm-linux --prefix=/opt/arm-tools --disable-threads --enable-languages=c
```

Comment: Do you have glibc-devel installed?

Comment: Yes: but why do you think that would help?  The linker being called is the cross linker, so using a native loader library would be ... wrong.

Comment: crti.o is a C library thing not a compiler thing, the bootstrap, linker script, etc are not a toolchain thing, you need something in addition to the toolchain, like glibc for that target that the cross tool can find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real answer is that it *should* compile `crti.o` ***if one was to build an arm-elf target.***  In building an *arm-linux* target, the *gcc* people reasonably assume that *glibc* has been compiled previously and it will provide the `crti.o` startup.  Perfectly reasonable, ***if you're upgrading***.

Building a new root file system is another story, a paradoxical one at that (which comes first: *glibc* or *gcc*?).  An approach (endorsed, but I've not yet succeeded with) is to build a stand-alone *gcc* (*arm-elf*\static, say) then *glibc*, then *gcc* again.

It seems as though some have addressed the missing `crti.o` in an *arm-linux* target by modfiying `gcc\config\arm\t-linux`.  Rather than relying on an unexisting *glibc*, the kludge is to use the *arm-elf* provided version of the `crti.o`.  An example can be found [here](http://frank.harvard.edu/~coldwell/toolchain/t-linux.diff).

```
--- gcc-3.4.4/gcc/config/arm/t-linux    2003-09-20 17:09:07.000000000 -0400
+++ gcc-3.4.4.works/gcc/config/arm/t-linux  2005-05-25 20:44:07.000000000 -0400
@@ -18,3 +18,24 @@

 # LIBGCC = stmp-multilib
 # INSTALL_LIBGCC = install-multilib
+
+EXTRA_MULTILIB_PARTS = crtbegin.o crtend.o crti.o crtn.o
+
+# If EXTRA_MULTILIB_PARTS is not defined above then define EXTRA_PARTS here
+# EXTRA_PARTS = crtbegin.o crtend.o crti.o crtn.o
+
+LIBGCC = stmp-multilib
+INSTALL_LIBGCC = install-multilib
+
+# Assemble startup files.
+$(T)crti.o: $(srcdir)/config/arm/crti.asm $(GCC_PASSES)
+   $(GCC_FOR_TARGET) $(GCC_CFLAGS) $(MULTILIB_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
+   -c -o $(T)crti.o -x assembler-with-cpp $(srcdir)/config/arm/crti.asm
+
+$(T)crtn.o: $(srcdir)/config/arm/crtn.asm $(GCC_PASSES)
+   $(GCC_FOR_TARGET) $(GCC_CFLAGS) $(MULTILIB_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
+   -c -o $(T)crtn.o -x assembler-with-cpp $(srcdir)/config/arm/crtn.asm
+
+# Disable libc link
+
+SHLIB_LC =
```