# How to cross compile into ARM9 board?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, poco-libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building ARM GNU Cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245295/building-arm-gnu-cross-compiler)

I am using POCO c++ library to implement my project in ubuntu environment. And I want to cross compile into the ARM9 based board from my POCO c++ code.

How to cross compile it for ARM9?

Answer (score 3):

Get a cross compiler for your target. Then take one of the cross-build configurations in $POCO_BASE/build/config (ARM-Linux, DigiEL, Angstrom, ELDK, etc.), copy it and make the necessary changes for your toolchain. You'll probably need to change the CC and CXX variables to match the executable names of your toolchain, as well as POCO_TARGET_OSARCH. The either set the environment variable POCO_CONFIG to the name of your build configuration and run make for Foundation, XML, etc., or run

```
./configure --config=<YourConfig> --no-samples --no-tests
./make -s
```

to build POCO for your target.

Also, the build system documentation at http://pocoproject.org/docs/99150-GMakeBuildNotes.html.

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637797/compile-poco-with-mingw-on-windowsc/14647307#14647307

Comment: Hi gunter ,following as your build documentation and after run on the ARM boards.then throws error like ./poco: symbol lookup error 
./poco: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4Poco3Net18HTTPRequestHandlerE

Comment: Are you sure you've linked your executable with all required POCO libraries (most likely libPocoFoundation, libPocoXML, libPocoUtil, libPocoNet)?

Comment: yeah,cross compiled in QT framework and that makefile whatever i included path for libraries as same path (put .so libraries) in the ARM-Linux board also .If lib is not proper location then throws libPoco*.so is missing.But in my case libPocoNet.so.16 is linked ,but HTTPRequestHandler not getting the definations.

Answer (score -2):

1. Build a cross compiler for your target.
2. Use the cross compiler to build for that target.

Comment: Oh yeah, pretty much. Good ol' sarcasm.

Comment: I can sense the wry, dry humor in this response sire. But please allow us noobs some leg room too!