# How to Cross Compile OMXPlayer on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: cmake, arm, cross-compiling, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to install omxplayer for my raspi, but as it is so slow, I wish to do it on my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop. I have followed the instructions for setting up a cross compiler as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269715/654789) (note, crosstools did not work for me). It mentions how to run it as such:

> Now you should be able to compile you cmake programs as easy as executing you cmake with this extra flag `-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/raspberrypi/pi.cmake`

But this does not help me as I have never used `cmake`. If I have a standard installation like so:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Where does `-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/raspberrypi/pi.cmake` fit into all that? Do I just change both occurrences of `make` to `cmake` =P I wish people would consider us noob programmers when answering these questions. This one poster made my blood boil with his [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14701859/654789). I have included the omxplayer `Makefile.include` file, which I presume is where I have to make some serious changes, as well as my cross compilation `.cmake` file, could somebody describe to me what changes I have to make and how they correspond to each other.

**Makefile.include:**

```
USE_BUILDROOT=0
FLOAT=hard

ifeq ($(USE_BUILDROOT), 1)
BUILDROOT   :=/opt/xbmc-bcm/buildroot
SDKSTAGE    :=$(BUILDROOT)/output/staging
TARGETFS    :=$(BUILDROOT)/output/target
TOOLCHAIN   :=$(BUILDROOT)/output/host/usr/
HOST            :=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
SYSROOT     :=$(BUILDROOT)/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot
else
BUILDROOT   :=/opt/bcm-rootfs
SDKSTAGE    :=/opt/bcm-rootfs
TARGETFS    :=/opt/bcm-rootfs
TOOLCHAIN   :=/home/dc4/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/
HOST        :=arm-linux-gnueabihf
#SYSROOT        :=$(TOOLCHAIN)/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/sysroot
SYSROOT     :=/opt/bcm-rootfs
endif

JOBS=7

CFLAGS          := -isystem$(PREFIX)/include
CXXFLAGS        := $(CFLAGS)
CPPFLAGS        := $(CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS         := -L$(BUILDROOT)/lib
LD                  := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-ld --sysroot=$(SYSROOT)
CC                  := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-gcc --sysroot=$(SYSROOT)
CXX         := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-g++ --sysroot=$(SYSROOT)
OBJDUMP         := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-objdump
RANLIB          := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-ranlib
STRIP               := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-strip
AR                  := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(HOST)-ar
CXXCP           := $(CXX) -E
PATH                := $(PREFIX)/bin:$(BUILDROOT)/output/host/usr/bin:$(PATH)

CFLAGS          += -pipe -mfloat-abi=$(FLOAT) -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -fomit-frame-pointer -mabi=aapcs-linux -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -Wno-psabi -mno-apcs-stack-check -g -mstructure-size-boundary=32 -mno-sched-prolog
LDFLAGS         += -L$(SDKSTAGE)/lib -L$(SDKSTAGE)/usr/lib -L$(SDKSTAGE)/opt/vc/lib/ -Lpcre/build
#INCLUDES       += -isystem$(SDKSTAGE)/usr/include -isystem$(SDKSTAGE)/opt/vc/include -isystem$(SYSROOT)/usr/include -isystem$(SDKSTAGE)/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -isystem$(SDKSTAGE)/usr/include/freetype2
INCLUDES        += -isystem$(SDKSTAGE)/opt/vc/include -isystem$(SYSROOT)/usr/include -isystem$(SDKSTAGE)/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -Ipcre/build -Iboost-trunk -Ifreetype2/include
```

**raspi.cmake:**

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /mnt/UEF/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /mnt/UEF/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /mnt/UEF/rootfs)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Comment: Hi did you find answer to it? I am stuck with it. TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Openembedded for OMXPlayer to compile, it's the easiest way to get things compiled without worrying too much on flag setting .

`meta-raspberrypi` is available here https://github.com/martiert/meta-raspberrypi.

Learn some basics of `OE`  Then begin your work.

To be simple in my existing project, I tried it and I'm successful.

After setting the configuration, run the make called "omxplayer."

Otherwise, if you're not good enough in "OE," just try to understand BB file called "OMXPlayer."

http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/tree/recipes-multimedia/omxplayer/omxplayer_git.bb?h=master

And try to cross-compile individually by checking dependencies.

**ADDITION**
If you're unfamiliar with open-embedded Go for `BUildroot`  Its an more easy then `OE`.

`git clone https://github.com/nezticle/RaspberryPi-BuildRoot.git`

`cd RaspberryPi-BuildRoot`

`make raspberrypi_defconfig`

`make menuconfig`

here Location:                                                                                      │
│     -> Package Selection for the target                                                          │
│       -> Raspberry Pi

Here, OMXPlayer will be enabled.

Finally:

`make`

The resulting package will be in output folder.

Comment: Going to give you the bounty, otherwise it goes to waste. I will, however, post an answer showing how I did it.

Comment: Hi did you find answer to it? I am stuck with it. TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

Does omxplayer have a CMakeLists.txt?

Then run this:

```
cd omxplayer
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/raspberrypi/pi.cmake
make
make install
```

No configure, no Makefile hackery.

Comment: There is **no** `CMakeLists.txt` file. Do I run the above to generate it, or only if the file already exists?

Comment: You run that command if it exists. As it does not exist, you don't use cmake to build omxplayer. So, you're asking the wrong question already :).

Comment: Basically I'm up poops creek without a paddle?